# How to select non-consecutive options of multiple select using keyboard in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, select

Using only keyboard, how can I select non-consecutive options of a multiple select element. On Firefox or Windows explorer, I can simply ctrl+Arrow to move the focus and then space bar to select. But I don't see any way to make it work on IE.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I've been searching for this for quite a while today.  It turns out that it is possible to do multi-select on a select input in Internet Explorer, via the strange shortcut of shift+f8 then arrow keys to move up/down and space to select further items.

Source: http://www.webaim.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=155

HTH
Sam