# How do I select multiple non-consecutive options from an html multiple select using just the keyboard in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, accessibility

How do I select multiple non-consecutive options from an html multiple select using just the keyboard in chrome?

I am aware of methods in ie and firefox.

Comment: I don't think this question belongs here. Did you try at superuser?

Comment: Thanks, didn't really consider that.. I don't think it is massively irrelevant tho. Was asking from a Webdriver driven test perspective.

Comment: I have no idea why this was considered so off topic as to be closed. Seems a bit overkill and rather anal. I need this answer for development, and it certainly comes under "software tools commonly used by programmers". Not impressed.

Comment: Oh and this is the reason I asked this here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709639/how-to-select-non-consecutive-options-of-multiple-select-using-keyboard-in-ie?rq=1), guess you'll want to close that too!

Comment: @Arth we should start a reopen request :) i'll vote for ya

Comment: Agree there should be a reopen request. This is very relevant for developers (and testers). If I develop a site and it is not possible to select non-consecutive items with a keyboard then this would fail accessibility requirements. If there is no way to do this in Chrome then as a developer I would need to consider alternatives, like using check boxes to select, or some JavaScript, or something else. 
Please reopen.

Answer (score 10):

I have tried a few ways to do it, but could not get it to go. I filed [a bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=125585) regarding this. I will update this if i hear anything.

Comment: Thanks. Have seconded your bug!

Comment: If I don't hear anything in a few days, I will shoot a note to a person I know.

Comment: The bug was closed as a duplicate of an older bug – [90172 - Can't select multiple non-consecutive items in a select box with the keyboard - chromium - Monorail](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=90172).

Answer (score 3):

This will be fixed in upcoming chrome update 80.0.3953.0 (after 8-ish years).

- Ctrl+[Up|Down] - moves the focus independently from selection.
- [Ctrl+Space|Spacebar] - toggles selection of the currently focused item.

Thread: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=982450

Bug Fix: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/68562ee3f5eabfed9a480bfeb08d3d6bc7daa205

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you navigate through tabs to the multiple select element, then:

1. Press the right click button [ to the left of the right located Ctrl key ].
2. Press the ESC button.
3. Set the "selected" property of each option you want to select by typing, for example:

   document.getElementsByTagName("option")[0].selected = true; 
   document.getElementsByTagName("option")[2].selected = true;
4. Hit ENTER key
5. The submitting of the form is not part of the answer to the question but you could either press ESC again and press CTRL+L to navigate to the submit button OR some JavaScript submitting.

You can try this here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit_view.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple

Comment: Ty but I must admit i'm confused by this, and it does not appear to work in my chrome. Was also hoping for a solution that didn't involve writing a line of JavaScript for each option!

Comment: This technically does answer the question.

Comment: @kzh, I was actually trying to do this by sending key presses via Webdriver.. so this isn't really usable. It also doesn't really work from a broader accessibility standpoint either. Nevertheless, I have upvoted the answer as useful.

Answer (score 1):

A user should be able to use Ctrl + click to select multiple options in a select list.

Using the keyboard, you could hold Control, use the arrow keys to get to the option you wanted to select, then use the space bar to select an option.

On a Mac, you can replace the Control key with the Command key and everything else should be the same.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work for me in chrome.. but does in firefox. I am aware of ctrl-clicking but require a keyboard solution.